# Using Alphabets get this pattern in PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

Desired Pattern is this

[image]

USING THIS CODE

```
order = int(input("Enter the order : "))
c = ord("A")
d = 1
for i in range(order,0,-1):
    for j in range(i):
        print(" ",end=" ")
    for k in range(1,d+1):
        #c=c-1
        print(chr(c),end=" ")
        c=c+1
    d=d+1
    print()
```

I am getting this pattern:

```
      A 
    B C 
  D E F 
G H I J
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same approach, slightly changing your second inner loop and how you update `c` should work:

```
order = int(input("Enter the order : "))
c = ord("A")
d = 1
for i in range(order,0,-1):
    for j in range(i):
        print(" ",end=" ")
    for k in range(0, d):         # iter from 0 to number of letters in the row
        print(chr(c - k),end=" ") # backtrack from starting letter
    d=d+1                         # increment d before updating c
    c = c + d                     # update c to be the starting letter of the next row
    print()
```

Returns

```
Enter the order : 4
          A 
        C B 
      F E D 
    J I H G
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `print(chr(c))` you essentially need to reverse the direction `c` is moving since you want to print the letters in reverse order. This is easy enough and can be done with just a few extra lines.

First, `c` should start out at the *last* (alphabetically) ascii value for the character you want to print (on that specific line). This is done by saying `c += d` right before your `for k` for loop.

Then, since we're going backwards, we need to decrement `c` by 1 each time. We add `c -= 1` at the very start of your `for k` loop.

Finally, we need to push `c` back to the next letter. Since we printed `d` letters, we just add `c += d` *after* the `for k` loop. This last bit might seem a bit confusing. As an example, one of the lines printed is `J I H G`. After printing this line, `c` has the ascii value of `G` but we want to be able to print the *next* letter after `J` and not `G` which is why we add the value of `d` again.

The completed code is

```py
order = int(input("Enter the order : "))
c = ord("A")
d = 1
for i in range(order,0,-1):
    for j in range(i):
        print(" ",end=" ")
    c += d
    for k in range(d):
        c -= 1
        print(chr(c),end=" ")
    c += d
    d += 1
    print()
```

Output:

```
Enter the order : 6
            A
          C B
        F E D
      J I H G
    O N M L K
  U T S R Q P
```

**P.S**

1. Instead of writing `x = x + 1`, it is more pythonic to say `x += 1`. This is the case for all the other mathematical operations. `x = x*3` can be re-written as `x *= 3`.
2. `for k in range(1, d+1)` can be written more succinctly as `for k in range(d)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, also for suggestions. I am a new coder so i am not very much familiar with short versions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler method to create your output.

```
cols = int(input("Enter the order : "))
end = cols - 1
c = ord('A')
for r in range(cols):
    l = [chr(c+count) for count in range(cols-end)]
    c=c+len(l)
    l.extend(' '*end)
    end = end -1
    l.reverse()
    print(' '.join(l))
```

Output:

```
        A
      C B
    F E D
  J I H G
O N M L K
```